# Why do I have to put at @s in a execute command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is my command block so far:

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:diamond_block
```

Then a comparator going into a command block:

```
say hi
```

In the first code, if I don't put `at @s` it doesn't work, why is that?

And what does a comparator do next to a command block?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I suppose it's Java, you didn't mention the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@s` target selector is used to target the entity that is executing the command. This is often referred to as "yourself" in the Minecraft help.

`@s` must refer to a in-world target entity, and command blocks are not entities. It does nothing in a command block unless you do `execute as <some_target>` first.

If you only use `as @a` the command is actually still running at the location of the command block, so you are checking only the block below it. Using `at @s` it runs the command relative to your coordinates.

Regarding the [Command Block / Comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Comparator#Miscellaneous):

> A command block stores the "success count" of the last command executed, which represents the number of times the most recently used command of this command block succeeded. The comparator outputs the number of times it succeeded.

Comment: wait so this would only go off if the block below the command block was a diamond?
and wont the `at @s` just  be the command block

Comment: or is it because im executing at the players location because as @a. i understand how to make it work i just want to know why it works. Thanks in advance. also what does the comparator do?

Comment: @The_SCP_Master yes, without `at @s` that will only check the block below the command block. And I've added the comparator part.

Answer (score 0):

When using `as` that doesn't tell the command where it tells what/who and using `at @s` it tells the command where and if you set it to `@s` it will set the position to itself.